# php foreach shows only results for an x result in one of my rows

Tags: php, foreach

There is a forech search, I want to get the results only where $postType<2 . How can I amend my code?

```
<?php
if ($resultSearch){
foreach ( $resultSearch as $row ){
$idPost=$row['idPost'];
$postType=$row['type'];
$postTypeName=getTypeName($postType);
$postTitle=$row['title'];
$category=$row['category'];//real category name
$fcategory=$row['fcategory'];//frienfly name category
$idCategoryParent=$row['idCategoryParent'];
$fCategoryParent=$row['parent'];
$postImage=$row['image'];
$insertDate=setDate($row['insertDate']);
if ($row["hasImages"]==1){
$postImage=getPostImages($idPost,$insertDate,true,true);
}
else $postImage=getPostImages(true,true,true,true);//there's no image 
$postUrl=itemURL($idPost,$fcategory,$postTypeName,$postTitle,$fCategoryParent);?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ( $resultSearch as $row ) if ($row['type']<2) {
```

Answer (score 1):

you mean like this :

```
if ($resultSearch){
foreach ( $resultSearch as $row ){
$idPost=$row['idPost'];
$postType=$row['type'];
if($postType<2)
{
  //do what you want..
}
....
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if ($resultSearch)
{
   foreach ( $resultSearch as $row )
   {
      $idPost=$row['idPost'];
      $postType=$row['type'];
      $postTypeName=getTypeName($postType);
      $postTitle=$row['title'];
      $category=$row['category'];//real category name
      $fcategory=$row['fcategory'];//frienfly name category
      $idCategoryParent=$row['idCategoryParent'];
      $fCategoryParent=$row['parent'];
      $postImage=$row['image'];
      $insertDate=setDate($row['insertDate']);
      if ($postType < 2)
      {
         if ($row["hasImages"]==1)
         {
            $postImage=getPostImages($idPost,$insertDate,true,true);
         }
         else
         {
            $postImage=getPostImages(true,true,true,true);//there's no image 
         }
         $postUrl=itemURL($idPost,$fcategory,$postTypeName,$postTitle,$fCategoryParent);
      }
   }
}
?>
```